# Android service does not start with setInexactRepeating

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I'm trying to create a service that increments some variables every 10 seconds permanently. To do so, i used setInexactRepeating to launch it in onCreate of MainActivity, but the service is never created...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Mothership mothership;
    AlarmManager manager; 
    Calendar calendar;
    Intent i;
    PendingIntent pIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mothership = (Mothership) getApplicationContext();
        mothership.initTopBar((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.exposure_eye),(TextView) findViewById(R.id.energy_level), (TextView) findViewById(R.id.human_number));
        mothership.data.changeCurrentActivity(DynamicData.Main);

        manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimerService.class);
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0); // paramètres à analyser
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        // Service
        manager.cancel(pIntent);
        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES/90, pIntent);
}
```

TimerService only contains 2 instructions in order the variables when it's called :

```
public class TimerService extends IntentService {

private final static String TAG = "TimerService";
Mothership mothership;

public TimerService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    incEnergy();
    decStealth(); 
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mothership = (Mothership) getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


public void incEnergy() {
    mothership.data.energyInc(); 
    mothership.topbar.update();
}

public void decStealth() {
    mothership.data.exposureDecrease(); 
    mothership.topbar.update();
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've empirically found that for both inexact and exact (pre-19 when all become inexact) repeating alarms, the minimum time seems to be about 30 minutes. Even then, I've found the timing for repeating alarms to be wildly unpredictable. For instance, when I've asked for a 35 minute period, I'll get some alarms at about 35 minutes intervals, some hours apart, and some within a few minutes of each other.

I've found it much more predictable to just ask for a one-shot alarm and then resubmit a new one each time the alarm fires.

Comment: That's strange, but resubmit a new one-shot alarm every 10 seconds must not be very efficient... Should I rather use a handler inside my service or something like that ?

Comment: For a period of 10 seconds, I doubt any alarm-based solution would be very efficient. I agree that a handler or other in-process solution would perform much better.